# Set filename of zip file download

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following code in a web api controller endpoint for downloading a zip file.  It works but the file name isn't being set right so I am trying to use the content disposition header to fix that.  However i get this error since i added that line `The format of value 'inline; filename=log_2016.zip' is invalid.`  How can I solve this issue?

```
 httpMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
 httpMessage.Content = new StreamContent(response.GetResponseStream());
 httpMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
 httpMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =new ContentDispositionHeaderValue (GetContentDisposition((HttpWebResponse)response));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the code for `GetContentDisposition(HttpWebResponse)`, I'm assuming based on the error message that this functions returns the full header text.

The constructor of `ContentDispositionHeaderValue` takes just the type (I believe it's `"inline"` in your case. You then have to set the remaining properties as properties on the `ContentDispositionHeaderValue` object.

If you already have the full `Content-Disposition` header text, use `ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse` or `ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse`.

Comment: I am not so sure that inline is the correct type, why do you think it so?

Comment: I don't think it's correct either (it's usually `attachment`), but based on the header in your error message, that seems to be what you're getting.